# Error publishing Azure runbook

Tags: azure, azure-automation

After creating a runbook in Azure automation, I get the following error when I try to publish it:

An error occured while publishing the runbook 'TidyNotifications'. Error details: InternalServerError: Error 1205, Level 13, State 52, Procedure Core.PublishRunbook2, Line 95, Message: Transaction (Process ID 789) was deadlocked on lock | communication buffer resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction..

As the error says, there's some other process involved. I tried closing the browser to the portal and re-connecting to make sure I didn't have the runbook open anywhere else but still get the same error.

Anyone come across this or can suggest the way forward?
Thanks.

Comment: try recreating runbook (delete this and create another), try incognito mode, try in half an hour.

Comment: Thanks. I just tried publishing it again after half an hour and it published okay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in this case the answer was to try again later. Cloud ;)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you can help the caching by signing out and signing in again. Otherwise, copy your runbook code, then press *Revert to published*, finally paste the copied code and save the runbook. Now, *Publish* the runbook. This will trigger Azure to do its job.

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure you don't have any errors in your run book with syntax. If you edit it and save it again it will tell you. Errors prevent you being able to publish it.